# Remove matching class with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

I want to remove matching class like `type-one` before adding new class like `type-two`

**HTML :**

```
<div class="demo test">
    <span>One</span>
    <span>Two</span>
    <span>Three</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$(document).on("click" ,".demo > span", function(){
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");


        $(this).parents(".demo").removeClass(function(i, c){
            return c.match(/type-[a-z]{0,5}/);
        })

        $(this).parents(".demo").addClass("type-"+$(this).text().toLowerCase());

})
```

My code is still adding and adding , cant remove the old matching class.

What I am doing wrong ?

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/X5JxV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c.match(/type-[a-z]{0,5}/)` is returning an array with one element.

You need to specify an index, i.e. `c.match(/type-[a-z]{0,5}/)[0]`, but first you should check that a match as occurred, otherwise an error will be thrown.

```
$(this).parents(".demo").removeClass(function(i, c){
    var m = c.match(/type-[a-z]{0,5}/);
    return m ? m[0] : m
})
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$(document).on("click" ,".demo > span", function(){
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(this).parents(".demo").removeClass().addClass("demo type-" + $(this).text().toLowerCase());
});
```

Here we remove *all* class names including `demo` and then reset it again with new `type-xxx` class.

Comment: This is work too , But many classes added by jQuery before loaded :D , Thanks anyway :D